# How to print int n values

Tags: java

I am new to Java and just start my journey but i have problem with this simple function.
I am should have result like that
*2345
**345
***45
****5
But my function return something else :D What should I have to change?

```
public class Main08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String row = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j < n) {
                    System.out.println(row += "*");}
                 else {
                    System.out.print(n);}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char[] array = "12345".toCharArray(); for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { array[i] = '*'; System.out.print(array); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j <= i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(j + 1);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Your issue is, that you prolonged the string multiple times and every time print it out again. I changed it such, that I only print out the numbers and asterisks depending on how the i and j relate to each other.

Also i limit the outer loop to n-1, because otherwise you will print 6 blocks (because you are starting from zero) and have a block of only asterisks at the end.

Output: `*2345 **345 ***45 ****5`

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a way to replace some characters in an existing string.
The easiest way is to use the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class because you can manage the characters, while a String is an unmodifiable sequence of characters:

> A mutable sequence of characters.

In particular you need to use the method [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,int,java.lang.String)) that:

> Replaces the characters in a substring of this sequence with characters in the specified String

So to pass from an original string `12345` to `**345` for example you need to do the following:

```
 // THe original string
 String original = "12345";

 // THe StringBuilder populated with the original string
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(original);

 // Replacing the first two characters (so 12) with the string **
 // to obtain the stringbuilder holding **345
 stringBuilder.replace(0, 2, "**");

 // Get the string **345
 String result = stringBuilder.toString();
```

You can put this logic in your loop and apply it multiple times.
Eventually you can reuse the same `StringBuilder`, so in this case you need to replace a single character for each step of your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main08 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n = 4;
            int countStar=0;
            int startNum=1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            //for displaying the "*"
                 countStar++;
                 startNum++;    
                for (int j = 1; j <= countStar; j++) 
                        System.out.print("*");
    
                //for displaying the digit
                for (int k = startNum; k <= 5; k++) 
                        System.out.print(k);
                }
           }
       }
```

You can take a outer loop and inside the outer loop take two inner loops . one for printing * and the other for printing the digit. This can help you in solving other design problems if you understand the logic.

Comment: Thanks
Also useful but for solution they want me to use "if".

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    String row = "";
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        row += i;
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(row);

        buf.replace(0, i, "*".repeat(i)); 

        System.out.println(buf);
    }
 }
```

The first loop create the initial row you want, and the second loop will replace the characters by stars.
The repeat appends * with same long as iterator i dynamically

Comment: Hello @Maxime welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer is unclear, the code you provided cannot fix the proposed question, feel free to test here: https://www.mycompiler.io/new/java
Please make sure you understand the question and that your answer is the solution to it.
How to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer